# run Windows 7 designed applications on XP

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-office

I recently acquired a copy of microsoft office pro plus 2013 for my computer (running windows XP) and tried to install it, but only to learn that it is designed for windows 7 and 8, and wont run on XP or Vista. is there any way to force it to install on XP?

Comment: Short answer, No, Microsoft went to great lengths to code this to only run on W7 or higher, so even if you could force it to install somehow it would not run in XP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The APIs that Microsoft Office 2013 use for everything they do simply don't exist on XP.

Comment: Woudn't prevent hackers from copying DLLs around and modify the binaries though. I though 2013 is completely based on .Net. It's a shame they're pulling this business trick...

Comment: thanks for the answer! i guess i will have to buy another HDD and get 7 on that :P